# Какие виды или алгоритмы комбинированного обучения существуют?

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект

Нашел слайд, где говорится, что способы обучения  в компьютерных системах делятся на:

1. Дедуктивное, или аналитическое, обучение (экспертные системы).
   Имеются знания, сформулированные экспертом и как-то формализованные.
   Программа выводит из этих правил конкретные факты иновые правила.
2. Индуктивное обучение (статистическое обучение). На основе
   эмпирических данных программа строит общее правило. Эмпирические
   данные могут быть получены самой программой в предыдущие сеансы ее
   работы или просто предъявлены ей.
3. **Комбинированное обучение.**

Приведите пожалуйста виды и алгоритмы комбинированного обучения.

Comment: нашёл видимо первоисточник информации, это научно-популярная лекция
Н.Ю. Золотых [Как обучаются машины?][1] и там более точно указано: 

 - Комбинированное обучение, содержащее элементы как дедуктивного, так и аналитического обучения.



  [1]: http://www.uic.unn.ru/~zny/ml/Others/ml_pop.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел неплохое описание. И оно (кажется) сделано с помощью манинного переовда. Но можно посмотреть и оригинал.
Выбор алгоритмов машинного обучения Microsoft Azure
Памятка по алгоритмам машинного обучения
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/machine-learning/studio/algorithm-choice
25.04.2017 Время чтения: 29 мин

Коротко, с иллюстрациями графиков.
С наилучшими.